# TagHelper for ViewComponent rendering

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-tag-helpers, asp.net-core-viewcomponent

Before reinventing the wheel (not sure if possible in this case!), is there a snippet of code showing how to invoke a ViewComponent within a Tag Helper implementation?

Edit: Including code from Taylor's [talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jD4H-CBab9o)

```
private readonly IViewComponentHelper _viewComponentHelper;
public ShapeishTagHelper(IViewComponentHelper viewComponentHelper) {
    _viewComponentHelper = viewComponentHelper;
}

[ViewContext]
public ViewContext ViewContext { get; set; }

public string Name { get; set; }
public int Age { get; set }

public override void Process(TagHelperContext, TagHelperOutput output) {
    output.TagName = null;
    ((ICanHasViewContext)_viewComponentHelper).Contextualize(ViewContext);
    var viewContent = _viewComponentHelper.Invoke("Shapeish", Name, Age);
    output.Content.SetContent(viewContent);
}
```

Comment: See my talk [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jD4H-CBab9o) which covers exactly that (as the last `TagHelper` example).

Comment: `ICanHasViewContext`has been renamed to `IViewContextAware`.